# How to use grafana variable values to calculate other results

Tags: python, grafana, influxdb

I have created the below variable in Grafana and would like to use them to calculate other results. I am working on calculating weather prediction from pressure to show if it going to rain or have sunshine.

The idea is to get the average value of the pressure for 30m, 60m, 90m, 120m,...360m
Here is a short example of python code:

```
import os
import shutil
import rrdtool

# Pressure average for now, 30m and 60m  
press0 = 1003
press1 = 1004
press2 = 1004

# Calculate the single differences
pdiff1 = (press0 - press1)*2
pdiff2 = (press0 - press2)**

# Calculate the average of the differences
pdiff_mean = (press1 + press2)/2
```

In Grafana I have added the below variables:

```
press0 -> influxDB
from(bucket: "test_enviro")
  |> range(start: -30s)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "rpi-bme280")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "air-pressure")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["location"] == "xxxx")
  |> mean()

press1 -> influxDB
from(bucket: "test_enviro")
  |> range(start: -30m)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "rpi-bme280")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "air-pressure")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["location"] == "xxxx")
  |> mean()

press2 -> influxDB
from(bucket: "test_enviro")
  |> range(start: -60m)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "rpi-bme280")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "air-pressure")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["location"] == "xxxx")
  |> mean()
```

How can I now add another variable that will do something like `($press0 - $press1)*2` for `pdiff1` variable?

Small update, I managed to go further and have now some math expressions, like:

[image]

So, now I have variable `pdiff1` and `pdiff2` and can now calculate `pdiff_mean`:

[image]

My problem now is again how can I take the value from `pdiff_mean` and use it to show specific text according to some value condition?
Example:

```
    if pdiff_mean > 0.75:
        show text unstable
    elif pdiff_mean > 0.42:
        show text sun
    ...
```

How can I do that in Grafana in a right way?
I have something like that now but it just gives me 0 and 1:

[image]

When the `pdiff_mean` value is smaller 0.75 it will return `outcome75=0` and if it is greater 0.42 it will return `outcome42=1`

But I rather would like to get a text back depending which condition is true.

Update:
I am now using value mapping to achieve the value from pdiff_mean to display a specific text, e.g.

If the calculation of `pdiff_mean = 0.16` the value mapping will show Stable right since it is between the range -0.25...0.25

[image]

The value mapping with the different ranges is not yet complete.